# Duplicated items if I follow 2 feeds with intersecting items in getstream-io

Tags: getstream-io

User1 follows feed1 and feed2. Activity1 is added to both feeds (image user follows 2 playlists and the same song was added to both playlists at the same time because these are system playlists by genres).
What happens then? Will user1 see two records in his timeline? song1 is added to feed1 and song1 is added to feed2?

Answer (score 2):

uniqueness is determined based on the foreign_id and time field. If you specify both these fields, Stream will understand uniqueness and you'll only see the activity once.

Note this only works if the activity is identical. If you need to group similar activities, aggregated feeds will work well.